# SQL Server - assign value to a field based on a running total

Tags: sql-server

For a customer, I'm sending through an XML file to another system, the sales orders and I sum the quantities for each item across all sales orders lines (e.g.: if I have *"ItemA"* in 10 sales orders with different quantities in each one, I sum the quantity and send the total).

In return, I get a response whether the requested quantities can be delivered to the customers or not. If not, I still get the total quantity that can be delivered. However, could be situations when I request 100 pieces of *"ItemA"* and I cannot deliver all 100, but 98. In cases like this, I need to distribute (to `UPDATE` a custom field) those 98 pieces FIFO, according to the requested quantity in each sales order and based on the registration date of each sales order.

I tried to use a `WHILE LOOP` but I couldn't achieve the desired result. Here's my piece of code:

```
DECLARE @PickedQty int
DECLARE @PickedERPQty int
DECLARE @OrderedERPQty int=2

SET @PickedQty = 
WHILE (@PickedQty>0)
BEGIN

    SET @PickedERPQty=(SELECT CASE WHEN @PickedQty>@OrderedERPQty THEN @OrderedERPQty ELSE @PickedQty END)
    SET @PickedQty=@PickedQty-@PickedERPQty
    PRINT @PickedQty

    IF @PickedQty>=0 
        BEGIN

            UPDATE OrderLines
            SET UDFValue2=@PickedERPQty
            WHERE fDocID='82DADC71-6706-44C7-9B78-7FCB55D94A69'

        END


    IF @PickedQty <= 0
        BREAK;
END
GO
```

**Example of response**

I requested 35 pieces but only 30 pieces are available to be delivered. I need to distribute those 30 pieces for each sales order, based on requested quantity and also FIFO, based on the date of the order. So, in this example, I will update the `RealQty` column with the requested quantity (because I have stock) and in the last one, I assign the remaining 5 pieces.

```
ord_Code  CustOrderCode  Date        ItemCode   ReqQty   AvailQty   RealQty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
141389       CV/2539     2018-11-25   PX085      10        30         10
141389       CV/2550     2018-11-26   PX085       5        30          5
141389       CV/2563     2018-11-27   PX085      10        30         10
141389       CV/2564     2018-11-28   PX085      10        30          5
```

Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be useful here. Check out the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: @EricBrandt - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more verbose than it needs to be, but I'll leave it to you to skinny it down if that's possible.

Set up the data:

```
DECLARE @OrderLines TABLE(
   ord_Code      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,CustOrderCode VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,[Date]          DATE  NOT NULL
  ,ItemCode      VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,ReqQty        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,AvailQty      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,RealQty       INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @OrderLines(ord_Code,CustOrderCode,[Date],ItemCode,ReqQty,AvailQty,RealQty) VALUES (141389,'CV/2539','2018-11-25','PX085',10,0,0);
INSERT INTO @OrderLines(ord_Code,CustOrderCode,[Date],ItemCode,ReqQty,AvailQty,RealQty) VALUES (141389,'CV/2550','2018-11-26','PX085', 5,0,0);
INSERT INTO @OrderLines(ord_Code,CustOrderCode,[Date],ItemCode,ReqQty,AvailQty,RealQty) VALUES (141389,'CV/2563','2018-11-27','PX085',10,0,0);
INSERT INTO @OrderLines(ord_Code,CustOrderCode,[Date],ItemCode,ReqQty,AvailQty,RealQty) VALUES (141389,'CV/2564','2018-11-28','PX085',10,0,0);

DECLARE @AvailQty INTEGER = 30;
```

For running totals, for SQL Server 20012 and up anyway, `SUM() OVER` is the preferred technique so I started off with some variants on that. This query brought in some useful numbers:

```
SELECT
  ol.ord_Code,
  ol.CustOrderCode,
  ol.Date,
  ol.ItemCode,
  ol.ReqQty,
  @AvailQty AS AvailQty,
  SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]) AS TotalOrderedQty,
  @AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]) AS RemainingQty
FROM
  @OrderLines AS ol;
```

Then I used the `RemainingQty` to do a little math. The `CASE` expression is hairy, but the first step checks to see if the `RemainingQty` after processing this row will be positive, and if it is, we fulfill the order. If not, we fulfill what we can. The nested `CASE` is there to stop negative numbers from coming into the result set.

```
SELECT
  ol.ord_Code,
  ol.CustOrderCode,
  ol.Date,
  ol.ItemCode,
  ol.ReqQty,
  @AvailQty AS AvailQty,
  SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]) AS TotalOrderedQty,
  @AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]) AS RemainingQty,
  CASE 
    WHEN (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date])) > 0 
      THEN ol.ReqQty
    ELSE 
      CASE 
        WHEN ol.ReqQty + (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date])) > 0
          THEN ol.ReqQty + (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]))
        ELSE 0
      END
  END AS RealQty
FROM
  @OrderLines AS ol
```

Windowing functions (like `SUM() OVER`) can only be in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, so I had to do a derived table with a `JOIN`. A CTE would work here, too, if you prefer. But I used that derived table to `UPDATE` the base table.

```
UPDATE Lines
SET
  Lines.AvailQty = d.AvailQty
 ,Lines.RealQty = d.RealQty
FROM 
  @OrderLines AS Lines
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      ol.ord_Code,
      ol.CustOrderCode,
      ol.Date,
      ol.ItemCode,
      @AvailQty AS AvailQty,
      CASE 
        WHEN (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date])) > 0 
          THEN ol.ReqQty
        ELSE 
          CASE 
            WHEN ol.ReqQty + (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date])) > 0
              THEN ol.ReqQty + (@AvailQty-SUM(ReqQty) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_Code ORDER BY [Date]))
            ELSE 0
          END
      END AS RealQty
    FROM
      @OrderLines AS ol
  ) AS d
   ON d.CustOrderCode = Lines.CustOrderCode
   AND d.ord_Code = Lines.ord_Code
   AND d.ItemCode = Lines.ItemCode
   AND d.Date = Lines.Date;

SELECT * FROM @OrderLines;
```

Results:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
| ord_Code | CustOrderCode |        Date         | ItemCode | ReqQty | AvailQty | RealQty |
+----------+---------------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
|   141389 | CV/2539       | 25.11.2018 00:00:00 | PX085    |     10 |       30 |      10 |
|   141389 | CV/2550       | 26.11.2018 00:00:00 | PX085    |      5 |       30 |       5 |
|   141389 | CV/2563       | 27.11.2018 00:00:00 | PX085    |     10 |       30 |      10 |
|   141389 | CV/2564       | 28.11.2018 00:00:00 | PX085    |     10 |       30 |       5 |
+----------+---------------+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Play with different available qty values here: https://rextester.com/MMFAR17436